# Website IP address doesn't match up with any EC2 instance IP addresses (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip-address

I've been asked to look at some non-technical friends' AWS account because they're worried about their costs, but I'm struggling to find where they're spending their money.  In particular I'm getting quite confused because the IP address of the website (according to the network inspector tools in my browser and `nslookup`) is different to every public IP address I can see on their AWS account.  Is it possible that any of the services they are using have a public IP address that matches their site, which perhaps forward requests?  Even then the usage doesn't match the bills.  I've tried using `traceroute` but it didn't help.

The services (as listed on their AWS billing page) they're using that I think might in anyway be related to the problem are: Elastic Container Service (ECS), Registrar, EC2 Elastic Load Balancer (ELB), EC2, VPC, EC2 Container Registry (ECR), CloudWatch, S3, Route 53, API Gateway, Lambda, CloudFront, and Relational Database Service (RDS).

Comment: *"the IP address of the website is different to every public IP address I can see on their AWS account."* - That is commonly the case when a website  uses **CDN** functionality such as Cloudflare  or the AWS equivalent CloudFront, the latter of which is listed in your billing overview.

Comment: @HBruijn thanks, I'll give that a closer look

Comment: Use the Cost Explorer tool in the AWS console, group costs by usage.

Comment: On top of CDN, the ELBs will have their own IPs that aren't Elastic IPs in the console.